# PHP Associative Arrays - Return all key value pairs where key is present in a validation list?

Tags: php, arrays, compare, associative-array, associative

For example:

```
$searchParameters = array(
    'parameter1' => 'value1',
    'parameter2' => 'value2',
    'parameter3' => 'value3',
);

$allowedParamters = array('parameter1','parameter2');
```

What's the best way to get `$searchParameters` containing only the allowed pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect_key()`](https://www.php.net/array_intersect_key) :

```
$searchParameters = array(
    'parameter1' => 'value1',
    'parameter2' => 'value2',
    'parameter3' => 'value3',
);
$allowedParamters = array('parameter1','parameter2');

$result = array_intersect_key($searchParameters, array_flip($allowedParamters));
```

Comment: Would this be heavier than using aforeach solution? It has to loop through each, and check the keys, but additionally there's the array_flip. This is the neatest way I've seen though!

Comment: `array_intersect_key()` has internal optimization, it won't use just loop. But in terms of memory this will be heavier, yes. In terms of time - you'll have to check this. My tests shown that `array_intersect()` [will win](http://3v4l.org/uqok4) (link will not show execution time since sandbox is blocking callbacks, but you can paste code from there and check)

Comment: Ok, this is probably better for smaller arrays then, anything huge and the other solution would save on memory. Thanks!

Comment: On huge arrays this will win by speed even more (because of internal `array_intersect_key()` optimization against plain loop). But if memory matters, then use loop, yes.

Comment: So this for speed, foreach for memory

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($searchParameters as $key => $value) {
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $allowedParamters)) {
        unset($searchParameters[$key];
    }
}
```

This will delete the not-allowed keys and their value.

Comment: This may be slower than the array_intersect_key method, but I think better for large arrays as it avoids cloning it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($searchParameters as $key=>$value){
    if(in_array($key,$allowedParamters)){
        $trueResult[$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($trueResult);
```